# How to instantiate Hebrew letters

Tags: fonts, letters

I want to make use of a Hebrew lamedh in a document instead of the Greek equivalent lambda as the latter is reserved another purpose. How do I get hold of this and other Hebrew letters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found precisely what I needed here: https://ctan.org/pkg/cjhebrew

Comment: The link is now dead, unfortunately.

Comment: @MichaelA I updated the link.